# Anyone know how to make TTabControl have an appearance more TTabSet alike?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I know that TTabSet is for 16-bit backward compatibility, yada-yada-yada.

But I really like its appearance; is there a way to make TTabControl look more like it?

Comment: The IDE use it. You can too.

Comment: Hard to say for how long the `TTabSet` control will be shipped with Delphi, but I understand that note about backward compatibility as "do not use it since it is not a part of Windows controls anymore". It is a control drawn by VCL so there's no need to worry about Windows version where you run an application with it. Just the users might be "confused" when they see it ;-)